# Product overlapping header

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I've never seen this before, but my product pages started overlapping my header.  Just product pages.  This began while I was adding a page with elementor (an exact replica of another page) and adding a product (a duplicate of another product).  Nothing different.  Nothing in any code editors.  I don't usually use elementor (prefer classic text editor) but I haven't had issues when I've used it before.

I added padding to my site in custom CSS, but that causes all regular pages to have padding above the header.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress creates a unique class in body for each page check below for screenshot

[image]

If you want to add css for a particular page without changing anything in your regular pages you can add like this

```
.uniqueclass header{
  padding:50px
  }
```